# Parity in --geth mode brings "unknown api" error

Tags: mist, json-rpc, parity, bug

I'm trying to migrate wallets from Mist to Parity. Parity is already fully synced and after using `--import-keys` I was able to import old Mist accounts into Parity. But the wallet contracts are missing so I need to run `parity.exe` with `--geth`.

Problem is, I get this error while launching parity:

```
Unknown api: rpcpersonal
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a confirmed bug and apparently fixed in the latest release.

https://github.com/ethcore/parity/issues/3263